# Can I publish iOS apps to App Store using osx on a virtual machine on PC?

Tags: macos

So I have a white macbook from 2008 and it's to old to download the newest Xcode. Could I put the new osx on a virtual machine and develop it trough there?

Comment: This question is about publishing, not developing

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you [this](http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/07/mountain-lion-virtualbox.html) it shows how to do it

Comment: In general, you should quote the material you are linking to, rather than just providing a link (which may go stale)